# Spark - Create table and insert constant values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What's the simplest way to create a temporary table with a single row using the spark shell? I tried insert into, but RDDs are write once only, right? I tried the below lines, but spark is very unhappy with the second.

```
spark.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW CAT (PAWS INT) USING PARQUET")
spark.sql("INSERT INTO CAT VALUES 4")
```

How do I do this? I'd like an in memory table, the same way as if I had read it in from a `csv`. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
scala> val res = List(4).toDF("Paws")
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Paws: int]

scala> res.show()
+----+
|Paws|
+----+
|   4|
+----+
scala> res.createOrReplaceTempView("CAT")
```

Comment: I'd like to use the SQL interface if at all possible, but since it's a table of constant values with only one row, seems like the easiest way might be to actually just create a csv and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataFrame to create table first -

```
 val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
        ("gyg1", 1, 1, 1, 1),
        ("gyg1", 2, 2, 2, 2),
        ("gyg2", 3, 3, 3, 3),
        ("gyg3", 4, 4, 4, 4),
        ("gyg3", 5, 5, 5, 5),
        ("gyg5", 6, 6, 6, 6)
      )).toDF("id", "a", "b", "c", "d")
// Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame.
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.
val results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM df")
```

check more here https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/sql-programming-guide.html